# How to allow https content within an iframe on a http site?

Tags: html, security, http, iframe, https

I've a site using http and I need to put an https iframe link in it. The iframe is working fine in all browsers except in Internet Explorer. I know it's related to domain security, but need to solve it.

The error message shown in IE: "This content cannot be displayed in a frame."

How can I solve this issue?

I also tried to change the https link like: "//domain.com" and https://managewp.com/user-guide/faq/how-to-enable-iframe-in-internet-explorer-10 but both didn't work.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame.

Is the message you get when you attempt to frame a page whose owner has asked for it not to be framed (using the [`X-Frame-Options` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)). This is not related to HTTP-vs-HTTPS, and it should fail on other newer browsers too.

Comment: No. It's working fine in other browsers. Issue exists only in IE.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=9" />` - I found this in header. It's working fine in IE 8, but not working in IE 9,10.

Comment: Hmm, that's not the correct form for that header (`IE=8,9` would be valid, although it would do nothing different to `IE=9` in practice). But I'm not convinced that is anything to do with the problem, which should be `X-Frame-Options`. Is the URL public anywhere?

Comment: You meant the iframe url ? Please clarify. The iframe url is public.

Comment: I've also tried to change the IE settings as mentioned in https://managewp.com/user-guide/faq/how-to-enable-iframe-in-internet-explorer-10 , but that also didn't help.

Comment: I mean can you point us to the thing you're trying to frame, so we can check the headers and try to reproduce the problem? It doesn't look like a mixed content problem as mentioned on that link (and enabling mixed content is in general not a good idea). The error message is specifically to do with `X-Frame-Options`.

Comment: Certainly `https://login.desk.com/` uses the HTTP header `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` to stop itself being framed deliberately. Same may be true of your address? Check the headers in debugging tools (F12), do you see `X-Frame-Options`?